# Allow RDP connection only from assigned OpenVPN IP address Server 2022

Tags: vpn, openvpn, windows-server-2022

Good day,
Firstly, Here is my setup: I have just set up a new Windows Server 2022. I am also registered with OpenVPN Cloud. I have installed the OpenVPN Connector as a service on the Server and it is connecting properly. In the OpenVPN Admin portal, I use the VPN IP address assigned to my server to connect to RDP, which works perfectly.
My question is, how do I "lock down" RDP to ONLY accept connections using the IP address assigned by OpenVPN Cloud and no other? I tried disabling the RDP preset rule but that locked me out completely, so I am unsure where to go from here. Any assistance would be most appreciated and apologies if it seems like I am asking a question that may have already been addressed, however, Icould not find any answers that fit my particular setup.

Comment: **I tried disabling the RDP preset rule but that locked me out completely** - What rule? Where? You should be able to use the Windows Firewall to accomplish this.

Comment: @joeqwerty the Server firewall rule in the Windows Firewall, Remote Desktop (User Mode). Yes, I am sure that it could be done via the Windows Firewall, I am just unsure exactly how as I am new to this setup and I am also 60 years old and learning as I go.

Comment: Hi all, not to worry, I managed to figure it out. Editing the existing Remote Desktop (User Mode) TCP Firewall rule to only allow a specific range of remote IP addresses worked perfectly. Thank you.